# Работа с рекурсией в PHP

Tags: php

Я некоторое время изучаю PHP, пока мне все понятно, но не понял как работают рекурсии в PHP... Теория ясна, что сама функция называет себя, пока не будет выполнено определенное условие в функции, я не понимаю, как работать с массивами в рекурсией... Спасибо.

```
Дан массив:

<?php
    $arr = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5];
?>
С помощью рекурсии выведите элементы этого массива на экран.
```

```
Дан массив:

<?php
    $arr = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5];
?>
С помощью рекурсии найдите сумму элементов этого массива.
```

Comment: что значит "не понимаю"? приведите пример кода который бы вы написали. напишите что именно не понимаете. как условие выхода прописать или что?

Comment: Например, чтобы распечатать каждый элемент отдельно от массива,я использовал CHR() и с рекурсией я конвертировал из 97-101 в буквами а затем я попытался напечатать каждый элемент отдельно но я убеждён, что делаю что-то не по правилам...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> С помощью рекурсии выведите элементы этого массива на экран.

```php
<?php
$arr = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5];

function r( $arr ) {
    //Если переданная на вход переменная является массивом и в ней есть хоть один элемент
    if ( is_array( $arr ) && count( $arr ) > 0 ) {
        //Получаем список ключей массива
        $keys = array_keys( $arr );    
        //Всегда выводим ПЕРВЫЙ ключ из списка и ПЕРВЫЙ элемент массива по этому ключу
        echo $keys[0]." => ".$arr[ $keys[0] ]."\n";
        //Удаляем ПЕРВЫЙ элемент массива и сдвигаем весь массив влево
        array_shift( $arr );
        //Вызываем сами себя еще раз (и так до тех пор пока в массиве не останется ни одного элемента)
        r( $arr );
    }
}

r( $arr );
```

Результат:

```
a => 1
b => 2
c => 3
d => 4
e => 5
```

> С помощью рекурсии найдите сумму элементов этого массива.

По аналогии с первой функцией пишем вторую

```php
function r( $arr, &$summ ) {
    //Если переданная на вход переменная является массивом и в ней есть хоть один элемент
    if ( is_array( $arr ) && count( $arr ) > 0 ) {
        //Получаем список ключей массива
        $keys = array_keys( $arr );    
        //Всегда суммируем значение ПЕРВОГО элемента массива по ПЕРВОМУ ключу
        $summ = $summ + $arr[ $keys[0] ];
        //Удаляем ПЕРВЫЙ элемент массива и сдвигаем весь массив влево
        array_shift( $arr );
        //Вызываем сами себя еще раз (и так до тех пор пока в массиве не останется ни одного элемента)
        r( $arr, $summ );
    }
}

$summ = 0;
r( $arr, $summ );

echo "summ = ".$summ."\n";
```

Результат:

```
summ = 15
```

Comment: Спасибо за глубокое объяснение. Теперь мне совершенно ясно, как это работает!